# How to build one virtual table with its heading coming from others table's values

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have 2 tables, where the inserts are due to a form filling. The first table, called **data**, register one line with an id. The other table, called **data_entry** register several lines: one for each field in the form. For 3 entries, it gives something like that:

**The first table:**

```
data

id
__
1
2
3
```

**The second table:**

```
data_entry

data_id    name     value
_____________________________________
1          name     John
1          age      35
1          email    j.smith@smith.com
2          name     Alex
2          age      20
2          email    alex@dot.com
3          name     Kenny
3          age      18
3          email    ken62@ggl.com
```

#### My needs

I want to display some of the data, **only with a SQL request**, in a table like this:

```
id    name     email
________________________________
1     John     j.smith@smith.com
2     Alex     alex@dot.com
3     Kenny    ken62@ggl.com
```

#### My temporary solution

I build my table with some PHP, and many queries in a loop, but I guess it's not the most beautiful (and opitmized) solution:

```
$tab = array(); // the table I create
$entries = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM data'); // the form entries

// for each entry, I create the row in my table
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    // I search for the 3 lines according to the same ID
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT name, value FROM data_entry WHERE data_id = ' . $entry->id );
    $line = array('id' => $entry->id);

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) { // I build my table's row with each result, except the age not needed
        switch ($row->name) {
        case 'name':
            $line['name'] = $row->value;
            break;
        case 'email':
            $line['email'] = $row->value;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
// now I can build the row in the table
$tab[$entry->id] = $line;
}
```

#### Is there a beter way to get the same result, with only SQL, or with only one request and a little PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you need.

```sql
SELECT id, name, VALUE
  FROM (SELECT DATA_ENTRY.ID,
               (CASE
                    WHEN data_entry.NAME = 'name' THEN data_entry.VALUE
                    ELSE NULL
                END)
                   name,
               (CASE
                    WHEN data_entry.NAME = 'email' THEN data_entry.VALUE
                    ELSE NULL
                END)
                   email
          FROM data INNER JOIN data_entry ON (data.id = data_entry.data_id))
 WHERE name IS NOT NULL AND VALUE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is very smart!! But there is always at least one NULL field in each row, so the final result is always empty. I'll try to manipulate the temporary table with the NULL fields, I have the feeling the solution is not far.

Comment: I did it, thanks to you!! I changed your temporary table in 2 tables, one with (id, name), and an other with (id, email). Then I did a join between those 2 tables, with a condition to avoid NULL values on name and on email. I will post an explicit code of the solution. Thanks to you again :)

Comment: Great. I'm glad for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this, please refer inline documentation for explanation

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT data_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(name,'=', value) SEPARATOR '@@@') nv   
FROM data_entry where name in ('name','email') GROUP BY data_id");

echo "<table><tr> <th>id</th> <th>name</th> <th>email</th> </tr>";
foreach ($query as $k => $v) {
    $temp = explode("@@@", $v->nv); // I have used double separator(inter row level)
    echo "<tr> <td> " . $v->data_id . "</td>";
    foreach ($temp as $v1) {
        list($name, $value) = explode("=",$v1); // same row level
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

> [Group_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html) Function. The GROUP_CONCAT() function in MySQL is
>   used to concatenate data from multiple rows into one field. This is an
>   aggregate (GROUP BY) function which returns a String value, if the
>   group contains at least one non-NULL value. Otherwise, it returns
>   NULL.

[list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) — Assign variables as if they were an array

Comment: Interesting way, first time I see the use of GROUP_CONCAT, and it does the job! I will use this, if I don't find a 100% SQL solution. Thanks a lot ;) PS: when I talk about creating a table, in fact I only need to get an array (which will be the table) containing arrays (for the rows). I have a function that creates my HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the solution I found thanks to @F.Lazarescu's reply:

```
SELECT tp1.id, name, email FROM (

SELECT data_entry.data_id id,
               (CASE
                    WHEN data_entry.name = 'name' THEN data_entry.value
                    ELSE NULL
                END)
                   name
          FROM data INNER JOIN data_entry ON data.id = data_entry.data_id
) tp1 
JOIN
(SELECT data_entry.data_ID id,
               (CASE
                    WHEN data_entry.name = 'email' THEN data_entry.value
                    ELSE NULL
                END)
                   email
          FROM data INNER JOIN data_entry ON data.id = data_entry.data_id
) tp2
ON tp1.id = tp2.id
WHERE
tp1.name IS NOT NULL
AND
tp2.email IS NOT NULL
```

And the result is just like I want it to be (and 50x faster):

```
id    name     email
________________________________
1     John     j.smith@smith.com
2     Alex     alex@dot.com
3     Kenny    ken62@ggl.com
```